# Cannot find module './git-host-info.js'

Tags: javascript, angular

I am following the official angular update instructions here [6.0 to 7.0](https://update.angular.io/#6.0:7.0). However, I get this error

> Your global Angular CLI version (8.2.2) is greater than your local
>   version (6.0.8). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch
>   false". Cannot find module './git-host-info.js`

I am not concerned about updating angular CLI at the moment.
Can anyone tell me what is this file `git-host-info.js' and why this error is showing up?

Answer (score 0):

git-host-info.js will let you identify and transform various git hosts URLs between protocols. It also can tell you what the URL is for the raw path for particular file for direct access without git.

you can run "npm i hosted-git-info" from Nodejs and then you will need to import it into your project.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: `then you will need to import it into your project.` where exactly I import it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error means that your `node_modules` are corrupted and you need to reinstall them.

```
npm cache clean
npm install
```

In some cases, you need to reinstall node and npm, or so I've heard, but I've always been able to get things working by just deleting my `node_modules`, updating node and npm and re-installing.

This is true whether or not you want to use the global Angular install.

Comment: the two commands did not help. The problem still exist! I will try to reinstall node and npm.